# Script to add hours and minutes of an individual user, then display on one line

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, last

New to Linux, lots to learn!
I am attempting to write a bash shell script in vi that will output the number of hours and minutes a user has been logged in over the last 7 days. I am working through errors due to my lack of understanding but I am having trouble achieving my desired result. Any assistance is truly appreciated!

Here is what I have so far for my weekly-login.sh

```
hours=0
for x in $(last -s -7days $USER | grep -v wtmp)
do
        a=$(echo $x | cut -b 51-52)
        b=$(echo $x | cut -b 54-55)
        hours=$((10#hours+=10#a))
        minutes=$((10#minutes+=10#b))
        echo "$hours $minutes"
done
```

At this time, my error is

```
-bash: 10#hours: value too great for base (error token is "10#hours")
```

I know I need to include 10# to convert octal to decimal, however I am struggling with syntax so I that it will display only the total hours/minutes

Comment: This particular error is because although `$((foo))` expands `foo`, `$((10#foo))` does not; you need `$((10#$foo))`. I'm not posting an answer because there's more to fix, e.g. mixing `hours+=` and `hours=` in one statement makes no sense.

Comment: You should use a simple awk script to get your result. It is neither effective to call so many proccesses, not recommended to use bash for calculations. Furthermore, you should research `last` output a bit more, for example, if a user is logged into more ttys concurently, you double-count times. Also you will have to include the current time, as there is no time value into the `last` output for the case of a session still open.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Yes, I understand parts do not work and may not make little sense, it is a learning process. Reading your comments has helped me  ```hours=0
minutes=0
for x in $(last -s -7days mouton | cut -b 51-52 | grep -v wtmp)
do
#       echo "$hours Hours + $x"
        hours=$((10#$hours+10#$x))
done
for y in $(last -s -7days mouton | cut -b 54-55 | grep -v wtmp)
do
#       echo "$minutes Minutes + $y"
        minutes=$((10#$minutes+10#$y))
done
echo "Mouton's login time for past 7 days"
echo "Total hours: $hours#!/bin/bash